# NullPointerException Socket - Android?

Tags: android, sockets, nullpointerexception, network-programming, serversocket

I am trying to use from this [LINK](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/).

Here is client code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5001;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    Button myButton;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                    String str = et.getText().toString();

                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                            true);
                    out.println(str);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

And here server code :

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    Handler updateConversationHandler;

    Thread serverThread = null;

    private TextView text;

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6001;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Get me bellow error and I can't see any message on server :

[image]

Comment: Put entire code this is not enough to check exception

Comment: The link of source code is here :https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Comment: Link is not enough, show your code so we can check exception

Comment: @ Vickyexpert . Ok.I edited my quetion .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: NullPointerException error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917586/android-nullpointerexception-error)

Comment: @ xenteros . My question is about socket.What does the Intent ?

Comment: Try to declare edittext instance outside methods as same as button declare then check

Comment: @ Vickyexpert.Not work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Client code, you haven't created the client-socket, but, you're trying to get the output stream of that socket using `socket.getOutputStream()`. Since socket is null, hence, your code throws NullPointerException.

So, create a socket object for client to connect to Server as shown below :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 5001;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
Button myButton;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                String str = et.getText().toString();
//create socket object as shown below before retrieving the OutputStream object.
                socket = new Socket(MainActivity.SERVER_IP,MainActivity.SERVERPORT);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                out.println(str);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}
//.... and your code goes on!
```